# mysql - How to update only the first row found from multiple duplicates rows

Tags: mysql, insert-update

this is what I have, 2 tables, and i want to update table #2 with the stock from the first table, but i want to update only the first row of each duplicate.

```
+----+------+
|code|stock |
+----+------+
|5001| 40   |
|5002| 20   |
|5003| 60   |
+----+------+

+----+------+----+
|code|stock |lot |
+----+------+----+
|5001|      | A  | < Update this
|5001|      | B  |
|5002|      | C  | < Update this
|5003|      | D  | < Update this
|5003|      | E  |
+----+------+----+
```

So here i have the same product on two or more rows, and i want to update only the one from lot:A, lot:c, and  lot: D, with the values from the first table.

How can i do this?

Comment: How do you define _first_?

Comment: I am thinking >>>> Database design error? Or maybe application design error

Comment: @Nae The one from above is the first one, and the one from below is the second one ;)

Comment: Sure but that depends on how the table is ordered. If not given, you're basically trusting whatever order you're given.

Comment: There is no 'above' and 'below' here. Rows in RDBMS tables represent unordered sets

Comment: @Strawberry, man, how you see the tables I created herem in this page?
The first one has 2 colums and is the first one and is above, and the other one has 3 columns and is below the first one, I'm talking visual, here, not in database.
I solved the problem anyway.

Thank you all for the answers! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using aupdate with join

```
update table2 t2
inner join  (
    select code, min(lot) lot 
    from table2
) t on t2.code  = t.code and t2.lot = t.lot
inner join table1 t1 on t2.code = t1.code 
set s2.stock = t1.stock
```